# Create server root relative image path in Asp.Net MVC 3 with XSLT?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, xslt

I'm trying to create image paths (in the src attribute) that are relative to the application root through XSLT.

I want this in the src attribute:

```
<img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/image.svg")" />
```

And if I insert this manually into the View files, it works fine. But I need to create the files by XSLT, since there are hundreds of them, created from XML. However, the XSLT will not let me insert the quotation marks, it escapes them with #34;

So is there any way to do this? How can I refer to the application root without this, and automatically get this path in XSLT?

I cannot use relative paths either, because due to the structure of the content, one controller action needs to be able to serve lots of different views found in a specific folder structure, based on id...

EDIT:

Actually, now I just tried

```
<img src="/Content/images/image.svg" />
```

and that worked fine! If I inspected the image path in the browser, it does get the application root concatenated with the string in the src... So how come everyone seems to be recommending you use @Url.Content()?

EDIT:

To clarify, the problem is getting this into an attribute in XSLT, with nested quotes. I assume this will be impossible, because it is not allowed in XML, but I need a workaround if anyone can think of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use**:

```
<img src='@Url.Content("~/Content/images/image.svg")' />
```

Comment: Sorry, don't know how I would do that... First of all, the src attribute is generated by <xsl:attribute name="src"> which itself generates double quotes around the Url.Content(). Also, I tried the other way around (manually), and then the compiler complains about "Too many characters in character literal", seeing it as a char I suppose. And even if that had worked, I think I would still have the same problem outputting single quotes in the XSLT transform...

Comment: @AndersSvensson: 1. Just verify that: `<img src='@Url.Content("~/Content/images/image.svg")' /> ` is a well-formed XML document (Which I have done). 2. Use AVT -- that is, write: `<img src='{$yourUrl}' /> ` where the variable `$yourUrl` contains the string that you are now specifying in `xsl:attribute`. There is *no* problem when you understand this solution.

Comment: I don't know if maybe I was unclear: the problem is not that the syntax doesn't work in the View file. The problem is to generate this value through XSLT...

Comment: @AndersSvensson: From this question one understands that the problem is in the nested quotes. If this isn't so, please, edit the question and explain the *real* problem.

Comment: @AndersSvensson: And if this is so, then my solution solves the problem. What is it you find problemetic with this solution? Just use it. If you haven't noticed, this solution avoids the nested quotes problem.